# Изменить цвет фона в контекстном меню android

Tags: java, android

Есть контекстное меню в файле menu_main.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.newventuresoftware.waveformdemo.MainActivity">

<item android:id="@+id/scale_1"  android:orderInCategory="100" android:title="@string/scale_1" app:showAsAction="always" />
<item android:id="@+id/scale_2" android:orderInCategory="100" android:title="@string/scale_2" app:showAsAction="always" />
<item android:id="@+id/scale_5" android:orderInCategory="100" android:title="@string/scale_5" app:showAsAction="always" />
<item android:id="@+id/scale_10" android:orderInCategory="100" android:title="@string/scale_10" app:showAsAction="always" />
<item android:id="@+id/scale_20" android:orderInCategory="100" android:title="@string/scale_20" app:showAsAction="always" />
<item android:id="@+id/scale_50" android:orderInCategory="100" android:title="@string/scale_50" app:showAsAction="always" />
<item android:id="@+id/scale_100" android:orderInCategory="100" android:title="@string/scale_100" app:showAsAction="always" />
```

Вызваю кодом:

```
    public void onScaleMenuButtonClick(View view)
{

    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(MainActivity.this, ScaleMenuButton);
    popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, popup.getMenu());
    popup.show();
}
```

Как поменять цвет фона всех элементов этого контекстного меню?

Answer (score 2):

Добавьте в `AppTheme`

```
<item name="android:itemBackground">@color/colorAccent</item>
```

---

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item...
    <item...
    <item name="android:itemBackground">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style/>
```